# How to ban a telegram chat user using a telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I can't find a way to ban or kick a user from a group chat using the pyTelegramBotAPI library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a blacklist. I would enter the user.id I want to block there. Then I would check "if the message is sent by a user who is on the blacklist, then this message should be deleted." Simply and without external means...

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.kick_chat_member(
    chat_id="-1001572091573", 
    user_id='123456789',
) #
```